# Why is the "submit" button invisible on the edit form in politics.stack?

Tags: bug, comments, editor, homepage

I have tried to edit a question with additional information this morning and this evening, but the edit page doesn't have a submit button.

[image]

In the security.stack forum homepage, one of my questions is blank.

[image]

Also, one of my comments is invisible too.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing. Are you running an ad blocker or some other kind of browser extension that could mess with page contents?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's because of a chrome extension called "cookie notification blocker", it only happens on some stack pages. Should I delete the query because it's a browser issue?

Comment: @com.prehensible no, post self answer so others with same extension will know how to solve this.

Comment: @com.prehensible I don't think the extension even had anything to do with it, the add-on does not look like something that can modify the layout.

Comment: It was indeed the privacy request extension, when I switched off that extension, the page worked again, and i only had the problem after having installed it.  it checks for javascript code that looks like a cookie privacy compliance form and erases it from the page.

Comment: @StackExchangeTornado any browser addon can, and usually does, remove and add any JS/CSS it wants. That's their whole purpose.

Answer (score 3):

It was a chrome extension called "cookie notification blocker" which can erase javascripts from the page. The page works fine prior to installing and after disabling the extension. I toggled the extension on and off and the politics submit form dissapeared and reappeared every time.